# How to implement two tables intersection on Doctrine2 Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Im pretty new on all this stuff so please excuse my foolness.
I have two tables, clients and orders.
I need to show on a template all clients with their total orders amount for each.
According to MCV model, I just want the controller to call a method of the Clients repository that returns an array with all the data ready for sending it to the template.
But I having problems with implementing this.
So in summary I have:

Entities:
Clients.php: with client.id
Orders.php: with a manyToOne relatioonship to clients, and a amount property.

DefaultController.php

```
public function indexAction()
{
 $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
 $clientsWithTotals= $em->getRepository('ACMEAppBundle:Client')->getClientsWithTotals();
 return $this->render('ACMEAppBundle:Default:index.html.twig',$clientsWithTotals);
}
```

ClientRepository.php:

```
class ClientRepositoryextends EntityRepository
{
  public function getClientsWithTotals()
   {
             ???     
   }
}
```

index.html.twig

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
{% block content %}
<table>
<thead>
 <tr>
  <th>Id</th>
  <th>Total</th>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 {% for entity in entities %}
  <tr>
   <td><{{ entity.id }}</td>
   <td>{{ entity.total }}</td>
  </tr>
 {% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

Many thanks indeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### First off the template is using a variable which hasn't been defined (`entities`):

```
return $this->render(
    'ACMEAppBundle:Default:index.html.twig',
    array(
        'entities' => $clientsWithTotals
    )
);
```

### Implementing the Repository:

```
class ClientRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function getClientsWithTotals()
    {
        $this
            ->createQueryBuilder('client')
            ->join('client.orders', 'order');
    }
}
```

As long as you have the oneToMany association correctly defined from Client to Orders and it's on the `$client->orders` property then the `join` will know that it has to filter out only the orders associated with a particular user.

### Implementing the `totals` virtual property:

Your `Client` object will have no way of knowing what the totals are unless you do one of the following:

1. select the value from the DB using an aggregation function like `SUM(orders.total) AS clientTotals`.
2. select the orders associated with a client from the DB (Doctrine2 will hydrate them into $client->orders) and then using a `foreach` loop to sum up all the values.

As described [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/aggregate-fields.html).

---

**Ex. for #1:**

You can construct a DQL query such as:

```
SELECT
        client,
        SUM(orders.total) as clientTotal
    FROM ACMEAppBundle:Client AS client
    JOIN client.orders AS orders;
```

The above query would normally return an array containing a all of the rows in the clients table in the following format:

```
array(
    'client' => $client // an ACMEAppBundle:Client entity object
    'clientTotals' => $clientTotals // an integer value representing the aggregate sum
);
```

Implementing a custom hydrator will allow you to decide what to do with the raw array data which is returned by the DB query.

**Ex. for #2:**

```
class Client
{

    ...

    public function getTotals()
    {
        $this->totals = 0;
        foreach ($this->getOrders as $order) {
            $this->totals += $order->getTotal();
        }

        return $clientTotals;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your were very detailed!
Now a final question! 
Can you clarify how to convert this sql query into a DQL one:

'select client.id, client.name, sum(order.amount) from client join order on order.client_id = client.id group by client.id'

Comment: Read the DQL docs and if you don't understand how post another question.